# Copyright issue of the interface of Windows Notepad

Tags: copyright, software, open-source-software

I'm developing Windows application. It is crypto-functioning notepad.

And its design(UI interface) is almost(approx 90%?) same with Microsoft Windows Notepad.

Differences are only some buttons and sub-windows for encryption and decryption.

I would like to distribute my program for non-commercial. In this case, can I use its UI interface legally?

[image: Text]

Comment: Microsoft probably *encourages* developers to maintain consistency in applications, so you shouldn’t have an issue. Years ago when I did some Apple S/W development, I read the Apple User Interface guidelines. I suggest that you find the equivalent Microsoft guidelines.

Comment: Previous discussion: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9716/copyright-issue-of-the-interface-of-windows-notepad

Comment: Then, how can I fill in the copyright blank in the program details? I mean Can I use "All rights reserved" or "Some rights reserved" and sth like that?

Comment: "All rights reserved" is obsolete according to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_rights_reserved